# class_exists fails to detect undefined class

Tags: php, class, error-handling

I am getting a PHP error that a particular class is not defined (when I reference a member method), and it's OK to be not defined in some cases.  So I created an IF statement to first check if the class exists, and then check that its method exists.  Now my IF statement is generating the error.  Here's the IF statement:

```
$visitordataavailable = ((isset($_SESSION['VISITOR'])) && (class_exists("Visitor",false)) && method_exists($_SESSION['VISITOR'],'toArray'));
```

And here's the error:

> Fatal error:  method_exists(): The script tried to execute a method or access a property of an incomplete object. Please ensure that the class definition &quot;Visitor&quot; of the object you are trying to operate on was loaded *before* unserialize() gets called or provide a __autoload() function to load the class definition  in...

How could this be generating an error!?  The class_exists is returning true that "Visitor" class exists, yet method_exists crashes because class "Visitor" is not defined.  Is a class 'defined' different from a class 'exists'?

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Myabe the class definition exists but do you reallay have an instance of it in `$_SESSION['VISITOR']`?? Has the class `__wakeup() __sleep()`? Better do an additional `is_object($_SESSION['VISITOR'])` check

Comment: `class_exists()` returns true if PHP can find the class (included/required, using auto loading etc). It does not tell you anything about the current state of it in your session variable.

Comment: JustOnUnderMillions: the is_object worked as I hoped!  Can you explain how an variable holds an object, PHP recognizes the class exists for that object, but is_object is false?

Answer (score 0):

You need to either instantiate the Class and pass the object to method_exists, or use is_callable and pass an array containing the Class name and the method name. You MUST include any namespace in the class name. So try

```
    isset($_SESSION['VISITOR']) && class_exists("Visitor",false) 
     && is_callable(array('Namespace\Here\'.$_SESSION['VISITOR'],'toArray'))
```

If you have no namespacing just use

```
    isset($_SESSION['VISITOR']) && class_exists("Visitor",false) 
         && is_callable(array($_SESSION['VISITOR'],'toArray'));
```

Edit:
Thinking about it you can probably dispense with the class_exists as its implicitly included in the is_callable check